# Flask render html using radio button

Tags: html, forms, flask

I am new to flask , trying to do small poc uisng radio buttons.  Please help me below.
suggest if my approach is wrong

1. in home page - i have 3 radio buttons with values (ENG, MEDICINE , MBA)
2. if MBA is radio button is selected, i am able to render MBA.HTML (next page) which again has 3 radio buttons (HR , FINANCE , MARKETING) .
3. on selecting HR - radio button am not able to render HR html page where i supposed to get user inputs (it says 405 module not found)

below code works and it renders to MBA html

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selectedValue = request.form['r1']
        if selectedValue == 'MBA':
            return redirect(url_for('MBA'))
        if selectedValue == 'ENG':
            return redirect(url_for('ENG'))
        if selectedValue == 'MEDICINE':
            return redirect(url_for('MEDICINE'))
    return render_template('index.html')
```

--inside MBA app route , checking if selected radio button in HR , render to HR html

```
@app.route('/MBA')
def MBA():
    return render_template('MBA_Home.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        aws_service = request.form['options']
        if aws_service == 'HR':
            return redirect(url_for('HR'))
```

```
home.html

<html>
<body>
<h2>
CHOOSE YOUR COURSE
</h2>
<font size= 4 face="verdana" color=#112244>
<form method = 'POST'>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="MBA" >MBA<br>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="ENG" >ENG<br>
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="MEDICINE" >MEDICINE<br>
<input type="submit" name="b1" value="Continue">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
MBA.html:
<html>
<body>
<h2>
CHOOSE YOUR STREAM
</h2>
<font size= 4 face="verdana" color=#112244>
<form method = 'POST'>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="HR" value="HR"> HR </input><br>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="FINANCE" value="FINANCE"> FINANCE </input><br>
<input type="radio" name="options" id="MARKETING" value="MARKETING"> MARKETING </input><br>
<input type="submit" name="b1" value="Continue">
```

Comment: Do you have a route for `HR`? In your example you have MBA route, but no HR route.

Answer (score 0):

First; you didn't specify methods for your MBA route, just like home() function, you need to specify your methods:

```
@users.route('/MBA', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def MBA():
```

After that, you need to return your render template at the end of your function:

```
def MBA():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        aws_service = request.form['options']
        if aws_service == 'HR':
            return redirect(url_for('HR'))
    return render_template('MBA.html')
```

Finally, we can not see your HR function, can you please also write that function so I can help you?